# How to access method of parent class from within a 'same name' method of the child class, using google glosure?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, google-closure-compiler

I am building an API using google closure.

I want to access a method of a superclass A, from within a method with the **same name** from the child class B.

Please, see the following pseudo-code:

**Superclass A**

```
class A {
    move: function() { ... }
}
```

**Child class B**

```
class B extends A {
    // B has its own 'move' method which uses the 'move' method from A
    move: function() {
        parentClass_.move();
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that the keyword 'parentClass' does this.
I read [here](http://bolinfest.com/essays/googbase.html) that it is the keyword 'superClass_' who does this.

None of them work. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Would someone please help me?

Thanks.

João

Comment: http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php under pseudo classical example

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the class is defined.  The syntax you use in your question doesn't match anything I know.

Ultimately, you need a reference to the super class, and the value must be defined in a way such that the subtype definition doesn't overwrite it.  Typically, this is done with the prototype object (but there are other way), in which case you can do:

```
A.prototype.move.call(this)
```

If this is Closure Library code, you can use:

```
B.base(this, 'move');
```